# str_detect for multiple pattern within each row

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse, stringr

Is there a way to filter rows based on match on 2 strings. For eg I want to get all the rows with name that contain `won` and `le`.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Cathy Wu","won Xion le","Matt le won","stephen leuig"),
                 value = 5:4)

name    value
<chr>   <int>
Cathy le    5
won Xion le 6
Matt le won 7
stephen won 8
James Matt  9
```

The output that I am looking for is;

```
name    value
<chr>   <int>
won Xion le 6
Matt le won 7
```

If I try `df %>% filter(str_detect(name,"won|le"))` then the result is as follows, as here it is doing an `or` (`|`)

```
name    value
<chr>   <int>
Cathy le    5
won Xion le 6
Matt le won 7
stephen won 8
```

What I am looking for is something like `"won&&le"`. Can I achieve this using `str_detect`.

Comment: Perhaps this approach would work: `df %>% filter(str_detect(name,"won.*le|le.*won"))`? Or, if you need "won" and "le" to be individual words (i.e. not part of another word, like "wonderful"), you can use the 'word boundry' marker `\\b`, e.g. `df %>% filter(str_detect(name,"\\bwon\\b.*\\ble\\b|\\ble\\b.*\\bwon\\b"))`

Comment: Great. This is what I am looking for. What `.*` mean. Can I find these information in documentation ? Can you please refer me there ?

Comment: In regex `.` is any single character and `*` is a "0 or more" quantifier. So `.*` matches literally anything: 0 or more of any characters. For more information on these, look for any intro to regex tutorial.

Comment: Regex information is explained in more detail in the vignette for stringr: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html (and there are many, many other resources available online to help you with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few different ways of doing it:

```
filter(df, str_detect(name, "won"), str_detect(name, "le")) # using multiple str_detect calls
filter(df, str_detect(name, "(?=.*won)(?=.*le)")) #  using lookaheads
filter(df, str_detect(name,"won.*le|le.*won")) # jared's first answer
filter(df, str_detect(name, "won") & str_detect(name, "le")) # another way similar to #1
```

To match the word, and not match the strings as part of larger words, as Jared commented, you can add a '\b' on either side of each word you're looking for, e.g.:

```
filter(df, str_detect(name, "(?=.*\\bwon\\b)(?=.*\\ble\\b)"))
```